# Garmin USB device on Win7 under Linux KVM

Tags: windows-7, usb, fedora, linux-kvm

I have a Fedora 16 installation and I'm using the Garmin Forerunner 610 HRM in the virtual machine. The problem is that I need to allow Windows 7 direct access to the USB stick that communicated with the Garmin watch.

I've been able to do it by always doing the following:

1. I start the windows 7 KVM and log in.
2. I plug in the USB stick
3. I add the corresponding USB device to the VM in virt-manager.
4. I use http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html to "enable" the USB device.
5. Shutdown VM and remove the USB device from the VM.

At this point Garmin's software finds the stick and I'm able to use it. What I'm curious about is what happens whenever I rip out the USB stick. When I did that setroubleshootd went crazy and starts taking up 100% of the CPU and almost 2G of memory. Thus I tried...

```
# sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log
  0% donesh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `{ rpm -qf /dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted); } 2>&1'
```

and then I keep getting this until hell freezes over. Is there a way of preventing this from happening? The actual line in audit.log that the script can't parse is:

```
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1336526335.863:206633): arch=c000003e syscall=16 success=no exit=-13 a0=1b a1=4008550d a2=7fff12ffb3a0 
a3=7fff12ffb530 items=0 ppid=1 pid=13343 auid=4294967295 uid=107 gid=107 euid=107 suid=107 fsuid=107 egid=107 sgid=107 fsgid=1
07 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="qemu-kvm" exe="/usr/bin/qemu-kvm" subj=system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c298,c678 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1336526335.863:206634): avc:  denied  { ioctl } for  pid=13343 comm="qemu-kvm" path=2F6465762F6275732F75736
22F3030312F303038202864656C6574656429 dev="devtmpfs" ino=523297 scontext=system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c298,c678 tcontext=syste
m_u:object_r:usb_device_t:s0 tclass=chr_file
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug somewhere. The process that tries call rpm on the "/dev/bus/usb/001/008 (deleted)" does not quote filename. You should report it.